# Google Calendar API: Checking if event exists on the cal

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have created code to add data from rows on a Google Sheets document to a Google Calendar. I am able to get this to work. However, my problem is if I add new events and then sync the calendar, the program adds the existing items again. The result is the new items are added and the existing items will be added again. How can I fix this? Is there a way to check for a specific event on the calendar?

```js
//Loop through the spread sheet and create an event for each row.
function addItemsToCalendar() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var games = spreadsheet.getRange("A5:C8").getValues();

  for (x = 0; x < games.length; x++) {
    var event_row = games[x][2];
    eventCal.createAllDayEvent(event_row + " vs. " + games[x][1], games[x][0]);
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("Sync to Calendar")
    .addItem("Sync Games", "addItemsToCalendar")
    .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Add a finish flag to you sheet or check existence of same event each time before creating a new one.

Comment: I added the following code and it worked! Thanks.
if(games[x][3] == ""){}

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full code solution. Thanks idfurw!

```
//Loop through the spread sheet and create an event for each row.
function addItemsToCalendar(){
  
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
    var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
    var games = spreadsheet.getRange("A5:D9").getValues();
    
    //if games exist then do nothing else add them to the screen.    
    for (x=0; x<games.length; x++)
    {      
          var event_row_opponent1 = games[x][2]; 
          var event_row_added_to_calendar = games[x][3];
          if(games[x][3] == ""){
              eventCal.createAllDayEvent(event_row_opponent1 + " vs. " + games[x][1],games[x][0]);
              console.log("Item added to calendar.") ;
          }
              
    }
     
}

function onOpen(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("Sync to Calendar")
  .addItem("Sync Sporting Events", "addItemsToCalendar")
  .addToUi();
}
```